# Add variable to group data by unique combinations of variables

Tags: r, tidyr, data-manipulation, dplyr

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(cbind((c(2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2017,2017,2016)), 
        (c('Ohio','Ohio','Arizona','Arizona','Nebraska','Nebraska','New Mexico','Idaho')), 
        (c('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H')), (c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))))
colnames(df) <- c('Date', 'Location', 'Var1', 'Var2')


      Date   Location     Var1 Var2
      2018   Ohio         A    1 
      2018   Ohio         B    2 
      2018   Arizona      C    3 
      2018   Arizona      D    4 
      2018   Nebraska     E    5 
      2017   Nebraska     F    6 
      2017   New Mexico   G    7 
      2016   Idaho        H    8
```

And I am trying to introduce a new variable, 'Combo' that will represent each unique combination of the 'Date'and 'Location' variables such that any row of observations that share the same date and location will have the same 'combo' value. I hope it to look something like this:

```
      Date   Location     Var1 Var2  Combo
      2018   Ohio         A    1     1
      2018   Ohio         B    2     1
      2018   Arizona      C    3     2
      2018   Arizona      D    4     2
      2018   Nebraska     E    5     3
      2017   Nebraska     F    6     4
      2017   New Mexico   G    7     5
      2016   Idaho        H    8     6
```

So that each combo value is shared by all the rows that have the same combination of date and location, regardless of the other variables in that row.

I was trying to use a combination of `mutate()` and `distinct()` but with no success. I'm hoping for a simple solution that is somewhat similar to:

Anyone have any ideas on this one? I've tried looking in the documentation for `distinct()` as well as `unique()` for ideas but no luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: The base R function `interaction()` is probably what you want, which returns a factor that you can then coerce to integer.

Comment: Or simply `df %>% mutate(Combo = group_indices(., Date, Location))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `.GRP` from `data.table` after grouping by 'Date', 'Location'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Combo := .GRP, .(Date, Location)]
df
#   Date   Location Var1 Var2 Combo
#1: 2018       Ohio    A    1     1
#2: 2018       Ohio    B    2     1
#3: 2018    Arizona    C    3     2
#4: 2018    Arizona    D    4     2
#5: 2018   Nebraska    E    5     3
#6: 2017   Nebraska    F    6     4
#7: 2017 New Mexico    G    7     5
#8: 2016      Idaho    H    8     6
```

---

Or using `rleid`

```
setDT(df)[, Combo := rleid(Date, Location)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Both

```
df <- mutate(df,Combo = as.integer(interaction(Date,Location,drop = TRUE)))
```

and

```
df <- mutate(df,Combo = as.integer(factor(paste0(Date,Location))))
```

are options, although they order the levels not in the order they appear in the data.